# How to properly add a third party framework to the ios part of a react-native project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, cocoapods, ssziparchive

Hi I am quite new to react native and I'm trying to integrate a third party dynamic framework, SSZiparchive, but it doesn't work. I found conflicting awnsers online that suggested using use_modular_headers! instead of use_frameworks! in the pod file, but it doesn't work either way.
Here is my podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'reactNative' do
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'SSZipArchive'
  config = use_native_modules!
  
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'reactNative-tvOS' do
  # Pods for reactNative-tvOS

  target 'reactNative-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

After this not working i added this lines to the podfile from a solution online:

```
pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => false
pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec', :modular_headers => false
```

Now I'm getting the errors

`Flipper-DoubleConversion.modulemap:1:8: Redefinition of module 'DoubleConversion'`

and

`stddef.h:102:10: Could not build module '_Builtin_stddef_max_align_t''`

and

`CoreFoundation.h:16:10: Could not build module 'Darwin'`

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution as it is adding in pod file and run pod update.  https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/1123#issuecomment-354431939